# MySQL - Get MIN and MAX time section

Tags: mysql

How could I solve this problem?

I have this:

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exaIX.png)

```
ID_HOME ID_TV   CO_CHANNEL  ID_TIME
460041  1       04          2128
460041  1       04          2129
460041  1       FE          2130
460041  1       FE          2131
460041  1       04          2132
460041  1       04          2135
460041  1       04          2140
460041  1       FE          2141
460041  1       FE          2145
460041  1       55          2146
460041  1       55          2159
```

I need this:

[Table I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osbEs.png)

```
ID_HOME ID_TV   CO_CHANNEL  MIN     MAX
460041  1       04          2128    2129
460041  1       FE          2130    2131
460041  1       04          2132    2140
460041  1       FE          2141    2145
460041  1       55          2146    2159
```

Pls help!

[DB_Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFVDJo842ePNDpmGaKAwGX/8)

Comment: I fear your question may not be well received, because it isn't laid out in a way that makes it easy for us to understand and to help you. Perhaps you could google "db fiddle" and make one for us

Comment: You should post the relevant information within the question instead of linking outside where ever possible, and, as Caius states you could use a fiddle application also to show a "working" example of your query. But remember, you need to put the primary information here in the question directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this

```
SELECT ID_HOME, ID_TV, CO_CHANNEL, MIN(ID_TIME) mini, MAX(ID_TIME) maxi 
        FROM TABLE_A 
        GROUP BY ID_HOME, ID_TV, CO_CHANNEL;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried to run it but it doesn't work. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFVDJo842ePNDpmGaKAwGX/3

Comment: It's partially correct, it's just not what I need. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFVDJo842ePNDpmGaKAwGX/8